# Child nodes generated with document.createElement in a nested list do not display

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div in my main html. I want to populate it with a nested list based on some json response data.

HTML:

```
<div id=myDiv />
```

JS:

```
function responseHandler(response) {

    var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

    for (var i = 0; i < response.OuterList.length; i++) {

        var outerDiv = document.createElement("div");

        for (var j = 0; j < response.OuterList[i].InnerList.length; j++) {

            var innerLabel = document.createElement("label");
           
            innerLabel.value = InnerList[j].something;

            outerDiv.appendChild(innerLabel);

        }

        myDiv.appendChild(outerDiv); 
    }
}
```

However, when the javascript executes, nothing is displayed in myDiv. What am I doing wrong? I've tried just adding a button for each loop of the outer list and that works fine. Also, if I replace the inner label generation with simple text using document.createTextElement(), that also works and is displayed.

I also did a console.out(myDiv) and I can see that the nodes are populated correctly, but they just aren't displayed.

Comment: Provide a [mcve]. Use the live demo feature of the question editor. Write valid HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` property is a feature of form controls.

`<label>` elements are:

- Not form controls, so don't have a `value` property
- Designed to label form controls, which you don't have any of, so are the wrong element to use here anyway

If you have a list, then use list makeup (`<ul>` or `<ol>` and `<li>` elements).

Add text content to them by creating text nodes with `document.createTextNode` and then appending them to the element with `appendChild`.